# Cloud Foundry OAuth token retrieved but get {"error":"Not authorized"} when POSTing to REST API

Tags: oauth, cloud-foundry, restful-authentication

SAP cloud platform uses Cloud Foundry to house some of its' services, like HyperLedger etc.

The following works if I do it manually:

I login to a cloud foundry instance  with a valid user name / password at https://login.cf.us10.hana.ondemand.com/login

That then redirects me to another host "blockchain-cockpit.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com" where I can successfully call the RESTful API's in question via the "cockpit" provided on the web page.

My goal here is to be able to call the RESTful services on "blockchain-cockpit.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com" using an OAuth token.

So I go to the command line to get an OAuth token using the following command:

```
curl -v -XPOST -H "Application/json" -u "cf:" --data "username=<username>&password=<password>&client_id=cf&grant_type=password&response_type=token" https://login.cf.us10.hana.ondemand.com/oauth/token
```

And that happily passes me back what *seems to be a valid" token.

For example:

> {"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImtleS0xIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.WgYaTeDqGcJfOpidmTLi06tJnDTC8eGigyWAaEsfDkRmOEWWJhK48dJVjZ43yCh_aECgKq__SUq7kLc48_yWRQ7fjDQSLPXRoZu-4X1YvVB-Xi68PnYAOTtnJFN_F7e6E43mLLNA5_5CdXJ8n88__sJXEoDknrI2R8inmolwIm8AtlvZlh_kuFtF5zt6_RudWkheP8GH8cDBXEEolj0jZtONrJ7bs88E_M07Rgo-fXSdOa6bPMGBCiGPWHqSfLsXGgSaFgeNkBu9_MygAcjx3v3QsQissHfORgzixTCVxT0fyWvoLyc-aWM-NrUzSZNq1hl33l99-QDFWq8sTplSh1Gz1G9y9eJEcH3KI_ycR7FRPmJ4l7eIEjXJm-0r05wqKKwnu8rdkX5hrv55-7qqaM_K32Pug6Sb_lBKfuccz_X7bHWtV7IbybiX_-jU2-CljDAZb6DNl9iTkHhSSKcIODpbItM5BD_AiOuCO8RviuD-P142sjwOD-1dQ9YhsvzQ66UZMjt05FNT7_SaYaxU_i5F6IBXFBmY-zFioIMdJyehGatgaxylqvjS_C_xv0Q7cLW_vsJvlv14AWnBhjD_-KO6oUoGN-llxRK8bo-a56ssfz2eBgNJjjroNw1nAqWU4cFmsOgD3Jni3wIpjBSGzh-ogdx63LCK60DVBu5y1NE","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImtleS0xIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.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.SsG45uw8qhSU1ulJ54QZdX8bNnykgGXUwzklBme4sjpNjLd2BuJbW0PHBY7_bHbNiPXplqVGSHsIixaUu-QYqFzs2ebjaGRfBeb9ElwPymI7PRak2gGbw6W1lwHLRpYtIQDp5Ezl9Exj9H_4YW8x7WV4Ca2zRhA8BxayKN7yqSdObR7FVNH0o6-8ZtYcpsHVNKu8KCWCkZ4kEBj4jAHrPmH7FV1AQMSTBK8P-iTWmDbWvsaa0RKxkfveCie_ESgAFt-Y8ZO3mu3zqNCxD238fQc3GJvpE2TPbaAAaSCcTRLBVWLFCiV-2VpmY7Fmv4R80RnzMkV1vOrkNutHNc4NYi3
>   dYf7JNRJ60Nox1jQRqoMuAS_VSGTiHAnLoOPVf7s0Y09wKuIeVwfB2UHFhs7UtKM7egJGKeZFAOcHAZNL8qbyqkRi0bkOOEMD0mqvEvMHEeS1o5KmYQ7zrxyNgQJgwJ98zMgOzHmC3NQ8o_sNZKTurxNqaPFsbmoB2tCoI9AkfaVdeDOd8tiY6XBAu5h76O7pag9RV4ch_nmViAPYwpD_ZxvwhB_3X0oqSKKNKzZaLW9ONip7yBmMhCub48D_zT26bOKUIYenO1LAV5aHjufsut7YxWBadrPSpGF-Oz6VYYeDqCerf7F8-rdA-RZYGUQBK-weTLJAfbQPn6CgTO4","expires_in":599,"scope":"openid
>   uaa.user cloud_controller.read password.write
>   cloud_controller.write","jti":"fe65662937a94774a52bc934bc5924c8"}*
>   Connection #0 to host login.cf.us10.hana.ondemand.com left intact

*Assuming* I now have a valid token I then try POST using POSTMAN and set the HTTP header:

**Authorization: Bearer #token from above#**

As mentioned before I am POSTing to "blockchain-cockpit.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com" and not the host I got the token from so not sure if that is a major issue here.

PostMan keeps giving me this error

> {
>       "error": "Not authorized" }

I then try the same using CURL using the following command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" -X POST https://blockchain-cockpit.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com/<remaining rest api> --data "test data"
```

I get the exact same issue:

**{"error":"Not authorized"}**

So my issue in my mind is if I login manually and interact with the api's on the site it works perfectly, yet when I apparently get a valid token and try post to the restful api's it keep failing?

Any ideas? I would really appreciate some help on this ;-)

Thanks

Lynton

Comment: are you sure that you should not pass more parameters in the 2nd call? oAuth requires more params (read the spec...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't call your chaincode via the blockchain cockpit API.

Like with every other Service on SAP Cloud Platform (e.g. MongoDB) you have to create a Service Key/Service Binding to get access to your Service Instance.

1. Login to the SAP Cloud Platform ([account.hana.ondemand.com](https://account.hana.ondemand.com/))
2. Navigate to the Space where you created the blockchain service instance and open the Service Instances page.
3. Open your blockchain service instance by clicking on the **name**
4. Click on Service Keys in the left navigation bar
5. Click `Create Service Key` and specify a name
6. You now see the access information to your service instance

   {
       "apiKey": "",
       "serviceUrl": "https://hyperledger-api.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com"
   }

You can get test the API by opening the service URL: https://hyperledger-api.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com

Regarding your question in the comments, to inject this information in a Java application you deploy you have to create a Service Binding and link the blockchain service instance to your application. The information of your service key will then be injected into the environment variables of your app. More information here: [SAP Help](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/e98280a71f17413088f8a10838a1e4cc.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the https://blockchain-cockpit.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com using an OAuth token. In my opinion this URL doesn't expose APIs which you want to consume and may need additional parameters.

I hope that you want to consume the blockchain APIs, there is a better way to do it. 
Navigate to the https://login.cf.us10.hana.ondemand.com/login

1. open up the Blockchain service instance that you created.
2. create a service key with a valid name.
3. Once service key is created, you will see generated json which contains apiKey and URL. Now you can make use of this URL and make calls to blockchain.

e.g. To post a transaction in blockchain:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'apiKey: <apiKey_which_you_receive_after_servicekey_creation>' -d '{ 
  "chaincodeId": "your_chaincode_id",
  "fcn": "your_func_name",
  "args": []
}
' '<URL_from_service_key_creation>/invoke'
```

And, replace invoke with query if you want to query a transaction from blockchain.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the detail above but my issue is when I go to the blockchain cockpit and deploy my chaincode in Go it just has a base URL, for example https://blockchain-cockpit.cfapps.us10.hana.ondemand.com/api/v1/hyperledger/<guid>/chaincode/invoke where I can pass in the JSON like you have above but that does not have any APIKEY? Sure, if I deploy, for example, some Java app to cloud foundry I have that APIKEY but now how could I link that URL I can POST to above to the Java application I deploy?